# how to display a array value in view page

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hai
      I am using codeigniter...I my function `phpcalview()`...
This is my function

```
function phpcalview()
 {
     $year = $this->input->post('yearvv');
  $data['year'] = $this->adminmodel->selectyear();
  $data['date'] = $this->adminmodel->selectmonth();
  print_r($data['date'] );

  $this->load->view('phpcal',$data); 
 }
```

I am printing the values with `print_r($data['date'] );`
I get values like

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [dbdatenum] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [dbdatenum] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [dbdatenum] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [dbdatenum] => 4 ))
```

I want to display the array seperately as `array[0],array[1]` in my view page how can i do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use foreach:

```
foreach ($your_array as $key => $value)
echo "[".$key."]=>".$value ";
```